# How to crop UIImage freely in swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on uiimage, on which i need to add a crop image functionality, like shown in image[image]

How can i do that? I don't want to use third party library for this.

Comment: What does cropping `UIImage` mean?  Removing the area you specify or clipping the area you specify?

Comment: i want to keep the area inside the white view. And also users will set the white view according to their need.

Comment: For a better idea i want to add same functionality like which is available in iPhone photos but i don't want to keep the area outside white view.

Comment: In case you didn't know, this isn't a place where you can place an order and somebody will write code for you.

Comment: Hey El i am not placing any order, i am just asking because everyone here on this website comes to ask question or find answer to their problem. If you don't know then it's alright. I am just asking here.

Comment: Use an `UIBezierPath` object to define a clip area.

Comment: Your question is far too broad as stated.

Suggest you break this down into multiple pieces and learn how to do each step and get that step working before moving on to the next step.  If you try a step and get stuck, ask a specific question about that step.

Comment: Something like (based on your image above):

1) Display an image
2) Allow user to select a rectangle within the displayed image
   2.1) Display the current selection
     2.1.1) Display the rectangle
     2.1.2) Display control points on the corners
   2.2) Allow the user to adjust the selection via control points on each corner
3) Allow the user to save their cropped image
 3.1) Crop the UIImage to create a new UIImage
 3.2) Save the new cropped UIImage to "disk" (or just return it for display at a higher level of the UI).

Comment: So it would help if you could let us know which step you are on, what you've tried and what specifically isn't working.

Comment: (sorry about the formatting of the steps outline; lost when posted)

Comment: Thanks for the steps, i will surely try these steps.

Comment: Welcome.  Like most programming projects, the first step is to divide it up into smaller more easily managed pieces.  Then work on those and build up your final solution.  Often all in a learning project / prototype project and then once you know how to do it all and have it working, make a nice clean final real solution in a new project and improve the code as you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to display the `UIimage`, how to draw the crop rectangle on top of the image, and how to allow the user to modify that crop rectangle, then the actual cropping could be done via `CGImage`'s `cropping(to:)` function documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping

There's a nice bit of sample code in the documentation for `cropping(to:)` at that link that implements a `cropImage` function in Swift that uses `cropping(to:)`.

Get the `CGImage` from the `UIImage` via the `cgImage` property on `UIImage`.

Comment: Sure!  If it works, mark answered so it's not left open.  If you're still stuck, drop a question here (or if it's on a different part of the task - how to display the crop rectangle over the top or whatever - consider asking a question about just that part).